# scala sbt - how to configure target directory structure?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use sbt to compile an existing project with a given directory structure. The sources are in a directory src/ and the compiled class files should go into a directory lib/

Both directories should have the same structure, that means src/package1/... should be compiled into lib/package1/... in the build.sbt I have

```
sourceDirectory <<= baseDirectory / "src"
target <<= baseDirectory / "lib"
scalaSource <<= sourceDirectory
javaSource <<= sourceDirectory
```

which works for the sources ... but in the lib-directory I have lib/scala-2.9/classes/package1/...

Is there any way to get rid of these scala-xx/classes and streams subdirs and generate only class files and place them directly in lib/ ?

Thanks,
d.

Comment: I recommend you not go against the grain. SBT uses an entirely different organization for project files, as you've seen. In particular, it has to segregate files by language and compiler version. You might be able to hack around it with some symlinks.

Comment: Ok, thanks ... then I might really skip to use sbt ...